# facebook sdk login for android, share and like buttons

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0, share-button

I've already implemented facebook login in my app. 
The issue I have is this:

I am using the native login for facebook, I have the Facebook app closed, with no user logged in. When I go to login to my app, once pressed login button the login form from Facebook app appears, I enter my credentials and get it. At this time, the Facebook app and my app both have the same user logged in.
   Now, I go to Facebook app, log out and login with a different user. If I go back to my app, obviously I still see the previous user and if I press shared or like button, app uses the user from Facebook app, so will post on a different account than the one that the user see in my app.
  Do you know how to fix this? Is there any way to check inside my app if the user id or token from Facebook app has changed?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AccessTokenTracker()` and `ProfileTracker()`